# Has anyone got a solution/workaround for CollectionContainer not being Freezable?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm trying to bind the `Source` of a `CollectionContainer` (or `CollectionViewSource` for that matter) to a `RelativeSource` Binding - I always get the following error

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

I understand this is due to `CollectionContainer` not being `Freezable` or not deriving from `FrameworkElement`.

Has anyone got a solution/workaround for this problem. I have seen talk of trying to implement their own `Freezable` `CollectionContainer` - any luck with this approach?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446699/how-do-you-bind-a-collectioncontainer-to-a-collection-in-a-view-model